# Font licence certificate in Android package

Tags: android

I want to use a special font for my Android application. Our client also got the licence for that font. But the managements asks if there is any special requirement to put the licence certificate in our android APk i.e. in Asset folder or something.

As of now i have not found any standard policy set by android platform to put the certificate in binary.
Please advice if there is any rule or process to be taken care to use the licensed fonts.